# Moving up/down methods in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I like organising my methods in a class so that protected functions are on the bottom, public on the top. Sometimes, I write a protected method on the bottom of the file and then I realize it's actually a public method.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to move methods up/down without using the standard cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) / paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) features in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Code | Move Statement Up/Down` <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Up/Down</kbd> -- no selection required: just place cursor in function declaration line.

**Alternatively:**
 
Configure your ordering rules at `Settings | Code Style | PHP | Arrangement` and then use `Code | Rearrange Code` (selection is required, AFAIK). If such action is not available then reformat your whole file (`Code | Reformat Code...`) -- it has an option to rearrange entries.

Comment: For Mac, to disable Mission Control's intercepting the shortcut keys, [set it in System Preferences » Mission Control](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24348/135238).